# Are sponges inherently inefficient when compared to other constructions?

Tags: authenticated-encryption, pseudo-random-permutation, poly1305, sponge

A sponge has by definition 'wasted' operations (the part of the state which always remains private but goes through all the ops of the permutation).

In return for that waste you get a MAC at the end - some claim that it's for free for some reason.

But the ops wasted on the hidden state cannot compete with something like Poly1305.

So the question is can you have a permutation such that it would be efficient on modern hardware to use it as sponge versus using it in a ChaCha (half-XEX) fashion accompanied by Poly1305? Or can you have an AEAD sponge construction that would allow a secure full state involvement?

Take for example the Keccak-p permutation (1600 bit state).

It would be more efficient to replace the ChaCha permutation in ChaCha20-Poly1305 with Keccak than to use Keccak in a sponge/duplex construction for AEAD.

Sponges are also vulnerable to DDoS because you have to go through the entire ciphertext before rejecting on the tag at the very end. Poly1305 will be an order of magnitude or more faster in rejecting.

Comment: One difference is that the sponge construction and Carter-Wegman MACs (such as Poly1305) have different security goals.  A sponge construction really is used as a hash (that is, has collision resistance), while Poly1305 cannot be used that way.  Given that sponge constructions have higher security goals, it's not surprising that they're more expensive.

Comment: sure, but in an AEAD scenario that doesn't really matter. And when comparing a sponge to a MD construction hash the same problem persists - wasted operations in the sponge. Typically the expansion operations used for msg blocks are very cheap. Sponges are very elegant constructions but it seems like they are doomed to inferior performance?

Comment: Well, for MAC performance, it's hard to beat a well-designed CW construction. There, the message processing part doesn't need any cryptographic properties (they need to meet some almost-universal properties, but that's easier, and also provable); so they can use an efficient algorithm to process message blocks (such as Poly1305's 'add-and-multiply-mod-$2^{130}−5$); a handful of multiplies is quite fast on high-end processors...

Comment: Note that for CTR mode you don't need to keep any state between the blocks other than the counter.  So I agree with poncho that the wider sponge operation to forward the capacity is weighted against the MAC construction. Where sponges might come into place is when HW support is added because in that case you can do about anything with the sponge other than unlimited signatures and asymmetric key encapsulation for encryption (for which we could use CRYSTALS in a PQC world).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Once sponge permutations are added to HW what's stopping you from getting even better performance by using the permutation with Poly1305 the way ChaCha does? That's the root of the question.

Comment: @LightTunnelEnd Transistors. You can e.g. create a smart card that is secure against quantum cryptanalysis by using just CRYSTALS (Kyber / Dilithium) and the Keccak sponge. All the other algorithms for the PRNG, key derivation, MAC, AEAD and of course hash can be created using the sponge. The only other functional hardware requirement to do cryptography is a TRNG.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I understand, but you can use the same permutation as a not-sponge to do all the same things more efficiently. Hence why the question was posted. Permutation + MD construct = hash, Permutation + ChaCha(half-XEX) Poly1305 type construction for AEAD and in all those cases it would outperform the sponge, so why bother?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes ChaCha was made into a hash, under BLAKE. You can actually use the BLAKE permutation as a sponge and performance will be inferior.

Comment: Yeah, OK, that is a good point. I'll have to dig into the details of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are sponges inherently inefficient when compared to other
> constructions?

In a way, yes. The sponge/duplex is [serial](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/1188) rather than [parallelisable](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00145-021-09399-8). However, there are ways of making permutation-based cryptography parallel, like [Farfalle](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/1188), [NORX](https://competitions.cr.yp.to/round3/norxv30.pdf), and [AEGIS-128X/256X](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/523).

Furthermore, as mentioned by @Maarten Bodewes, there is increasingly SHA-3 [hardware support](https://keccak.team/files/KangarooTwelve.pdf), which boosts [SHAKE based AEAD scheme](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/1494) performance, for example. Similarly, the hardware accelerated [AES round function](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/299) has been used for very [efficient](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/116) schemes in a way similar to the duplex construction. As an example, AEGIS-128X/256X is significantly faster than AES-OCB, AES-GCM, and ChaCha20-Poly1305 assuming the right hardware support. So are the non-parallelisable versions (AEGIS-128L and AEGIS-256), highlighting how duplex-style algorithms can be fast.

You also can't ignore the positives of the sponge/duplex constructions, such as ease of implementation, use case flexibility despite one primitive, considerable research, and so on. It has been the basis of many [CAESAR](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/792) and [NIST LWC](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/ir/2023/NIST.IR.8454.pdf) competition submissions, indicating a [shift](https://keccak.team/2017/not_arx.html) to permutation-based cryptography. If its performance was a problem, it would not have been this successful.

> In return for that waste you get a MAC at the end - some claim that
> it's for free for some reason.

The reason this is 'for free' is because a sponge-based AEAD scheme is [one-pass](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-21702-9_18.pdf) rather than [two-pass](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/206) like generic composition. In other words, you don't have to process the message again.

AEADs like AES-GCM and ChaCha20-Poly1305 are sometimes called [1.5-pass](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/46595/what-is-meant-by-a-1-5-pass-cipher) because even though they do Encrypt-then-MAC, the MAC computation is faster than collision-resistant MACs like HMAC.

> But the ops wasted on the hidden state cannot compete with something
> like Poly1305.

This is a good thing. Poly1305 isn't collision resistant like the sponge/duplex, which is required for [AEAD commitment](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/526). What people need to understand is that users of AEAD schemes intuitively expect them to have this property. Without it, [vulnerabilities](https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity22/presentation/albertini) arise in [protocols](https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/infk/inst-infsec/appliedcrypto/education/theses/project_MircoStauble.pdf). If the aim is security by default/preventing misuse, all future AEAD schemes should be [fully committing](https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/1260). The duplex is the most obvious and tried/tested way of doing this besides reverting to generic composition.

You can think of commitment as analogous to misuse resistance, except you would not intuitively expect a nonce-based AEAD scheme to be misuse-resistant. There are warnings about reusing a nonce everywhere. By contrast, nobody warns you about a lack of commitment and relatively few people understand when a protocol is vulnerable. Sure, there are ['patches'](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/Events/2023/third-workshop-on-block-cipher-modes-of-operation/documents/accepted-papers/The%20Landscape%20of%20Committing%20Authenticated%20Encryption.pdf) to existing AEAD schemes, but they're clunky (e.g. they increase ciphertext expansion or require replacing the AEAD tag, [may](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/sec21summer_len.pdf) produce timing side-channels during decryption, etc) or modify the scheme itself.

> Or can you have an AEAD sponge construction that would allow a secure
> full state involvement?

Again, full-state absorption [prevents](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/1525) AEAD commitment, what should be a fundamental security property. If you're still unconvinced that this is a problem, ask yourself why NIST wanted to discuss it in the [third workshop on block cipher modes](https://csrc.nist.gov/Events/2023/third-workshop-on-block-cipher-modes-of-operation), with 4 accepted papers on the topic. Since then, there have been [numerous](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/1495) [recent](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/1494) [publications](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/1525), adding to the literature starting in [2017](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/288) but only recently being taken more seriously.

The key takeaway is that whilst performance is great, it should not be the main goal. Cryptography is about security. Performance at the expense of meaningful security causes problems.

Comment: You list ciphers which have fast permutations due to hw acceleration and are used in a sponge construction. But is it not the case that you can take those same permutations and use them with a half-XEX construction (ex. ChaCha) and obtain even greater performance by pairing them with Poly1305?

Comment: How are you coming to that conclusion? That's not necessarily the case, and there are faster MACs than Poly1305. If you have a large state and rate, you can process [lots](https://www.hyperelliptic.org/DIAC/slides/PermutationDIAC2012.pdf) of data at a time whilst getting authentication 'for free' as explained, avoiding a second pass over the message. AES round function designs are more complicated. You also don't seem to be acknowledging the issue of commitment, which is exactly why I keep mentioning it. You don't want to be using Poly1305 or similar in a new design.

Comment: One of the papers you linked mentions that they fixed the commitment issue by simply including the nonce in the Poly1305 MAC. Is that not sufficient? I tried an experiment where I used the BLAKE permutation as a sponge hash vs. MD hash, performance was significantly degraded. How can it be otherwise?

Comment: Which paper? That doesn't work because Poly1305 isn't collision resistant, and that wouldn't be fully committing even if it did work. BLAKE wasn't designed for use in the sponge, and you're deviating between discussion of the sponge/hashing and the duplex/AEADs, which are completely different use cases. That's also one algorithm/experiment with presumably one set of hardware, so you cannot generalise that every sponge/duplex is slower than the alternatives. I suggest you look at benchmarks on [eBACS](https://bench.cr.yp.to/) and in papers/competition reports.

Comment: "Actually Good Encryption? Confusing Users by Changing Nonces"  You can also rely on preimage resistance by including both the key and the nonce in the MAC. BLAKE is not the exception, you can pick any permutation used as a sponge and convert it into a half-XEX + Poly1305  1.5 pass construction and performance will increase vs. the sponge construction.

Comment: If I recall correctly, it talks about authenticating the nonce via HMAC, not Poly1305. The terminology it uses is specific to the age tool. You need collision resistance for commitment. I'm not sure why you asked the question if you're 100% positive you already know the answer. AES round function constructions will certainly be more efficient.

Comment: It seems like getting key commitment is fairly easy, all you have to do is output the first block of ciphertext raw thereby committing to the key (equivalent to prepending 128+ 0's to payload prior to encryption). Once the receiver starts the verification process, even prior to Poly1305 it would be apparent if the key is correct.

Comment: https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-doc/blob/master/secret-key_cryptography/aead.md#robustness

Comment: Please read my discussion of how it's clunky. You shouldn't have to patch a design; it should be secure by design. Also again, the padding fix is only key committing, not fully committing. With standard cryptographic library APIs, you can't decrypt without verifying the Poly1305 tag, leading to a timing difference that may be exploitable. I'm going to stop replying now because you seem to be ignoring what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

Sponges are very versatile and simple with strong security. They are usually not optimal for each case performance-wise. Biggest performance issue is they are sequential (some are configurable parallel like NORX).

Comparing Sponges to ChaCha20-Poly1305 is unfair since Sponge has $2^{c/2}$ (where $c$ would be usually $2k$) all-around security while ChaCha20-Poly1305 is limited to $2^{64}$ outputs per key/nonce. Sponge is more resilient in nonce reuse case. Sponge is also fully committing which has already been mentioned.

Capacity in sponge could be considered as kind of tweak/key schedule rather than wasting operations. Although key schedule can be pre-computed, efficient parallel modes typically also require tweak. All that can make sponge more efficient when processing is limited to sequential and easier to analyze.

Take a look at [SpoC](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/lightweight-cryptography/documents/round-2/spec-doc-rnd2/spoc-spec-round2.pdf) which makes required capacity smaller by masking it.

Even full rate AEAD is possible with additional state and more complex mode: [Designing Full-Rate Sponge based AEAD modes](https://eprint.iacr.org/2023/1673)